# Python for starters - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thank you so much for reading my first post.

Started learning Python 3.6.1 - got stuck at the starter - what's wrong with following code:

```
print('Hi there! What is your name?')
myName = input()
print("Hello "   +  myName +  ' its good to met you. My name is Kendo.')

print('how old are you?')
myAge = input()
if myAge < 15:
    print('go to bed, kiddo')
elif myAge > 95:
    print('Sup, grandma')
elif myAge > 1000:
    print('Lol, stop kidding me')
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int, covers both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @Marko Petkovic I posted a small answer covering both python 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is a string, and you need to convert it to an int to use comparison operator.

Instead of :

```
print('how old are you?')
myAge = input()
```

Try this:

```
myAge = int(input('How old are you?')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need an **integer** but the input() returns a string.
You can convert the input to int using somrthing like the following:

For **Python 3.x**:

```
myAge  = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

For **Python 2.x**:

```
myAge = input("Enter a number: ")
>>>Enter a number: 5 + 17

myAge, type(myAge)
(22, <type 'int'>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Input returns a string object in python 3. You are trying to see if a string is smaller or greater than an integer. This does not work.

from the python 3.6 documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
input([prompt])
If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

try:

```
myAge= int(myAge)
```

Do however note that when when you give any non numerical character as input in the `myAge = input()`this will raise an other error. Since you can't force for non numerical characters into an integer.